# Installing GCC on SLES 12

Tags: package-management, gcc, sles, zypper

I'm having trouble installing `gcc` on a new SLES 12 box. The goal here is actually to get R Shiny running, but when I try to install any packages I get the below error:

```
sudo su - -c "R -e \"install.packages('Rcpp',repos='https://cran.rstudio.com/')\""
make: g++: Command not found
```

This leads me to believe I need to install `gcc`.

`which gcc`:

`which: no gcc in (/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/root/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/games)`

`gcc -version`:

`If 'gcc' is not a typo you can use command-not-found to lookup the package that contains it, like this:
    cnf gcc`

This is where the trouble begins. When I `zypper in gcc`:

`Problem: gcc-4.7-7.1.1.x86_64 requires gcc47, but this requirement cannot be provided
  uninstallable providers: gcc47-4.7.2_20130108-2.1.6.i586[oss]
                   gcc47-4.7.2_20130108-2.1.6.x86_64[oss]`

Ok.. `zypper in gcc47-4.7.2_20130108-2.1.6.x86_64`

Results:

`Problem: gcc47-4.7.2_20130108-2.1.6.x86_64 requires glibc-devel, but this requirement cannot be provided
  uninstallable providers: glibc-devel-2.17-4.4.1.i586[oss]
                   glibc-devel-2.17-4.4.1.x86_64[oss]`

Right then... `zypper in glibc-devel`

Results:

`Problem: glibc-devel-2.17-4.4.1.x86_64 requires glibc = 2.17, but this requirement cannot be provided
  uninstallable providers: glibc-2.17-4.4.1.i586[oss]
                   glibc-2.17-4.4.1.x86_64[oss]`

`zypper in glibc`

Results:
`'glibc' is already installed.

`No update candidate for 'glibc-2.19-17.72.x86_64'. The highest available version is already installed.`

So somewhere in this chain of dependencies an RPM needs a lower version of something I already have. I don't want to downgrade the system. Is there some way to get the most up to date GCC that will work with `glibc-2.19`? Am I doing something wrong here? Am I missing a repo?

```
SLSE12:~ # cat /etc/os-release
NAME="SLES"
VERSION="12"
VERSION_ID="12"
PRETTY_NAME="SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 12"
ID="sles"
ANSI_COLOR="0;32"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:suse:sles:12"


# zypper lr -u
# | Alias     | Name      | Enabled | Refresh | URI
--+-----------+-----------+---------+---------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1 | gcc       | gcc       | Yes     | No      | http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:/gcc/SLE-12/
2 | oss       | oss       | Yes     | No      | http://download.opensuse.org/distribution/12.3/repo/oss/
3 | r-patched | r-patched | Yes     | No      | http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:/languages:/R:/patched/SLE_12/
```

Comment: If repo " http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:/gcc/SLE-12/ " : There is no gcc47 any more. About "glibc-devel" : System files can be installed only when you have paid / activated your SLES account / license. I.e. SLES12 is a commercial OS. ...

Comment: There is however a gcc48, and R Shiny is likely agnostic to which version to use, so why would I not be able to use that?

Comment: Just try : `# zypper in gcc48-c++` ... or / and `# zypper in gcc-c++`

Comment: same error, just different package `gcc48-c++-4.8.5-161.1.x86_64 requires libstdc++48-devel = 4.8.5-161.1, but this requirement cannot be provided uninstallable providers: libstdc++48-devel-.8.5-161.1.x86_64[devel_gcc] libstdc++48-devel-4.8.5-161.1.x86_64[gcc]`

Answer (score 0):

We had the similar problem (needed to install `igraph` and `tidygraph`).
After registering the `SLES 12 SP3 SDK` the repo, which can be downloaded from [this link](https://download.suse.com/Download?buildid=Lsztjn71OI4~), we installed:
* gcc-c++
* gcc-fortran
From there on we managed to install all the problematic packages.